# CURLOPT_ Definitions

Tags: c, linux, curl

Where are the options for [curl_easy_setopt](http://linux.die.net/man/3/curl_easy_setopt) defined? I'm trying to look for the integer values of CURLOPT_VERBOSE and some others, but these don't seem to be explicitly defined in [curl.h](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/source/browse/mingw/include/curl/curl.h?r=19288e3798dc2003b9a67bbcfd437e7de3e34ef1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line 792:

```
#ifdef CURL_ISOCPP
#define CINIT(na,t,nu) CURLOPT_ ## na = CURLOPTTYPE_ ## t + nu
```

line 953:

```
CINIT(VERBOSE, LONG, 41),      /* talk a lot */
```

There it is.

Comment: Ah, did not notice the macro, my bad. Thanks!

Comment: The macro is unfortunate -- it makes searching for the definition much more difficult, and it probably also screws with various code indexing tools as well.

Comment: @santosh.ankr You're welcome. Piece of good advice for the future: you can 1. search for only the part of the macro name that varies ("VERBOSE" in this case), 2. if still nothing's found, pipe the header through the preprocessor to expand all the macros and remove black magic.